# Directory.GetFiles: Just list file in working directory

Tags: c#

I want to get the list of files in a folder. This is my code:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles("c:\\");
foreach (var f in files)
{
    Console.WriteLine(f);
}
```

My expectation:

```
C:\bootmgr
C:\BOOTNXT
C:\hiberfil.sys
C:\pagefile.sys
C:\swapfile.sys
```

But I got:

```
C:\a
C:\b
C:\c
```

`a, b, c` are files in working directory: `C:\Code\test\bin\Debug`

Is there a way to do it right?

Comment: `Program Files`, `Program Files (x86)`, `Users`, and `Windows` at the root of the `C:` drive would not be returned by `Directory.GetFiles` since they are directories, not files.

Comment: Show us the complete code. You might using wrong code to display files. Secondly, you are expecting folders as part of output, however you are calling GetFiles().

Comment: var dirs = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\").GetDirectories();

foreach (var dir in dirs)
{
       Console.WriteLine(dir.Name);
}

Comment: I think your code must be worked fine. But check your project properties page; open tab: Debug; in Start Options, keep Working directory blank. Try it, hope useful for you.

Answer (score 6):

Use `Directory.GetDirectories` method.

Comment: Looks like you edited question and now it says you need files at C drive's root level. Expected output before edit showed directories at C's root.